# Installation of SimpleITK for c++ Project fails with errors

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, conda, simpleitk

I have a C++ Project with cmake where I want to use SimpleITK (Red Hat Linux). I tried to follow multiple tutorials how to install SimpleITK but every one of them failed with errors.

I use conda environment for installing packages.
First thing I tried was to install it via conda like this:

```
conda install simpleitk
```

After that i was able to import SimpleITK in python and check the version (2.2.1).
But as I tried to use SimpleITK with C++ nothing worked.

I added this line to my CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(SimpleITK)
```

and tried to execute `make -j8`.
This produced following errors:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSimpleITK.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "SimpleITK", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SimpleITK" with
  any of the following names:

    SimpleITKConfig.cmake
    simpleitk-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SimpleITK" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SimpleITK_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "SimpleITK" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

I read on https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/master/link_CppCMake_docs.html that there are two variables needed to build a SimpleITK program, SimpleITK_DIR and ITK_DIR. SimpleITK_DIR needs to be set to the directory that contains the file SimpleITKConfig.cmake, and ITK_DIR needs to be the directory containing the file ITKConfig.cmake.

Next step was to download SimpleITK to the external folder of my project and to use this commands (from Docs SuperBuild section https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.1/building.html):

```
mkdir SimpleITK-build
cd SimpleITK-build
cmake ../SimpleITK/SuperBuild
```

But this also failed with errors:

```
CMake Warning at /external/SimpleITK/CMake/sitkSourceVersion.cmake:62 (message):
  git tag: "-128-NOTFOUND" does not match expected version format!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /external/SimpleITK/Version.cmake:17 (include)
  SuperBuild.cmake:487 (include)
  SuperBuild.cmake:493 (_set_simpleitk_install_path)
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (include)
```

The folders ITK-build and SimpleITK-build, mentioned in https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/master/link_CppCMake_docs.html, for setting the paths didn't contain the config files.

What am i doing wrong?
I'm really new to both, C++ and SimpleITK and at this point i am really desperate how to fix this problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Show more of the `cmake ../SimpleITK/SuperBuild` output. This might help to find out what exactly failed.

Comment: Using 'conda install' only installs the Python package. To use SimpleITK with C++ you're going to have to build the libraries from the source code yourself.

Comment: OK, looks like you're trying to build the source. But clearly that failed. I'd suggest asking people on the ITK discourse.  discourse.itk.org.